A subgroup $K$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if it is a union of conjugacy classes
I've come up with a question regarding a normal group and conjugacy classes.
In Paolo Aluffi's Algebra, proposition 11.57 says,

A subgroup $K$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if it is a union of conjugacy classes.

In this context, does the 'union of conjugacy classes' imply the union of conjugacy classes 'of $K$', not of $G$? Or is it a case that doesn't matter?
In the proof of the text, it defines $\hat{K}$ by the union of all the conjugacy classes of elements of $K$ and proves that $K$ is normal if and only if $K = \hat{K}$.
Searching for other people's proof online, I found that they are also considering the conjugacy classes of just $K$.
I just don't find any justification for the constraint to $K$. It might seems like a mere nitpicking, but I just wanted to double check. Thanks in advance!

The conjugacy classes of $K$ are a subset of the conjugacy classes of $G$. In this case, they are the only ones that matter.

if $K$ is a union of conjugacy classes of some elements of $G$ then it is the union of its conjugacy classes (all classes of elements in $K$).

I am not clear what you mean by "of $K$". It could mean that you look at the equivalence relation "is a conjugate of" inside $K$ for elements of $K$ (that is, $x\sim y\iff \exists g\in K (gxg^{-1}=y)$); or you mean equivalence classes for the relation in $G$ but which happen to be contained in $K$.

Given a group $\mathfrak{G}$ and elements $x,y\in\mathfrak{G}$, let us say that $x$ and $y$ are $\mathfrak{G}$-conjugate if and only if there exists $g\in \mathfrak{G}$ such that $gxg^{-1}=y$. This is an equivalence relation on the elements of $\mathfrak{G}$, and the equivalence classes are the $\mathfrak{G}$-conjugacy classes.
If $K\leq G$, and $x,y\in K$, then we have two different relations that may, or may not, relate $x$ and $y$. They could be $K$-conjugate, or they could be $G$-conjugate.
If $x$ and $y$ are $K$-conjugate, then they are certainly also $G$-conjugate; but the converse need not hold. For example, if $G=S_3$, $K=\langle (123)\rangle$, then $(123)$ and $(132)$ are $G$-conjugate (by taking $g=(23)$), but are not $K$-conjugate (since $K$ is abelian).
I understand your question to be whether the problem is talking about $G$-conjugacy classes, or $K$-conjugacy classes.
Note that because "is a $K$-conjugate of" is an equivalence relation on $K$, $K$ is always a union of $K$-conjugacy classes: namely, all the $K$-conjugacy classes. So that can't really be the statement, as it would tell us that every subgroup is normal.
What the statement says is:

A subgroup $K$ of $G$ is normal in $G$ if and only if it can be expressed as a union of $G$-conjugacy classes.

In proving that if $K$ is normal then it is a union of $G$-conjugacy classes, we start by looking at elements of $K$ and show that if $x\in K$, then the entire $G$-conjugacy class of $x$ lies in $K$. Why do we start with $x\in K$? Because there is absolutely no point in looking at $x\notin K$. If we let $[x]_G$ denote the $G$-conjugacy class, then we have
$$ K = \bigcup_{x\in K} \{x\} \subseteq \bigcup_{x\in K}[x]_G.$$
So what we want to do is prove that $[x]_G\subseteq K$ for all $x\in K$ to get an equality.
In proving that if $K$ is a union of $G$-conjugacy classes then $K$ is normal, we only look at the $G$-conjugacy classes that are contained in $K$, because we are asking about $K$, not about other elements.
